# jQuery .attr function not returning all attribute values

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling with a fairly basic problem using a jQuery (v 1.12.4) selector to get attribute values. The HTML page contains an svg element for which I am trying to select a number of attribute values:

```js
var svg = $("div.container-fluid > svg").first();
var viewBox = svg.attr("viewBox");
var svgHeight = svg.attr("height");
var svgWidth = svg.attr("width");
var preserveAspectRatio = svg.attr("preserveAspectRatio");
var zoomAndPan = svg.attr("zoomAndPan");
var css = svg.attr("class");

if (typeof(console) != 'undefined') {
  console.log("viewBox : " + viewBox + "; height : " + svgHeight + "; width : " + svgWidth + "; preserveAspectRatio : " + preserveAspectRatio + "; zoomAndPan : " + zoomAndPan + "; css class : " + css);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container-fluid"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" width="16.5354in" height="11.6929in" viewBox="0 0 1190.55 841.89"
    xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st15" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.1" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css">
```

For "height", "width" and "class" attributes the .attr() function returns the value as expected. However , for "zoomAndPan", "preserveAspectRatio", "viewBox" the .attr() function returns "undefined". Having debugged the Javascript in Chrome I can see that the svg DOM structure contains all of the expected attributes, hence cannot understand what the problem is.

Any assistance or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Andrew

Comment: I added jQuery to your snippet and it seems to work fine?

Comment: your selectors, for instance, `svg`, is a variable that's shortened the actual jQuery selector? Fx. `$('.someClass')` ? If not, it's nothing like the selector syntax I've ever seen in jQuery. Edit: Running your snippet, everything seems to work as expected? I don't see any error, I see all the values in the log being properly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - this seems to be a bug with v 1.12.4 - upgrading to v 3.5.1 fixed the issue